# Why use locator to link service classes - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand the use of the get_it package and locator.

In an [example](https://github.com/FilledStacks/flutter-tutorials/blob/master/040-firestore-crud/01-final/lib/services/authentication_service.dart) I noticed the author uses the locator to allow the `AuthenticationService` to use the methods of `FirestoreService`:

```
class AuthenticationService {

    final FirestoreService _firestoreService = locator<FirestoreService>();

    ...
```

What is the difference in using the `locator` and just initialing a class object as follows:

```
class AuthenticationService {

    final FirestoreService _firestoreService = FirestoreService();

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have real `FirestoreServiceImplement` and Mock `FirestoreServiceMockImplement` 
With `Service Locator`, you can easily `register` `Mock` Implement like this `locator.registerLazySingleton<FirestoreService>(() => FirestoreServiceMockImplement());`
in `setupLocator`

When use `final FirestoreService _firestoreService = locator<FirestoreService>();`
You will get `FirestoreServiceMockImplement` instead of `FirestoreServiceImplement`

code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

final locator = GetIt.instance;

abstract class FirestoreService {
  createUser(User user);
}

class FirestoreServiceImplement extends FirestoreService {
  Future createUser(User user) async {}
}

class FirestoreServiceMockImplement extends FirestoreService {
  Future createUser(User user) async {}
}

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton<FirestoreService>(
      () => FirestoreServiceMockImplement());
}


void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class User {
  final String id;
  final String fullName;
  final String email;
  final String userRole;

  User({this.id, this.fullName, this.email, this.userRole});

  User.fromData(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : id = data['id'],
        fullName = data['fullName'],
        email = data['email'],
        userRole = data['userRole'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'fullName': fullName,
      'email': email,
      'userRole': userRole,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m fairly new to this, so don’t really understand the difference between FirestoreImplement and FirestoreMockImplement?

Comment: Mock mean fake, you can return fake data such as for test or debug. So you do not need to put debug code in it.

Comment: But the author doesn't locate a mock version of FirestoreService 

`GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => NavigationService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => DialogService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => AuthenticationService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => FirestoreService());
}`

Comment: Author saide :  I was missing the ability to easily switch the implementation for a business object for a mocked one without changing the UI.

Comment: Demo code will not show everything. it just show important part. because Author come form .Net world , you can read Why get it. https://pub.dev/packages/get_it#why-getit